# implement an export and it's sub export in react

Tags: reactjs, import, export, es6-class

I meet opensourced ts library component and its sub components like following pattern:

```js
import {Box} from 'example/box';
```

```html
//in react
<Box>
   <Box.Left>
      Left
   </Box.Left>
   <Box.Right>
      Right
   </Box.Right>
</Box>
```

The question is: how can I implement the `Box` component in `jsx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Box` component needs to be the `export default` of the `Box.js` file. `Left` and `Right` are defined as properties of `Box`:

```
import React from 'react';

const Box = ({children = null}) =>
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>;

const Left = ({children = null}) =>
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>;

const Right = ({children = null}) =>
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>;

Box.Left = Left;
Box.Right = Right;

export default Box;
```